# Connection to Bluetooth device fail

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a `listView` of paired device and upon click on the selected index I will connect to it.

```
listView_pairedDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String deviceInfo = listAdapter_pairedDevices.getItem(position - 1);
                String lines[] = deviceInfo.split("\\r?\\n");
                String deviceAddress = lines[1];
                BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
                btChatService.connect(selectedDevice, false);
            }
        });
```

**`BluetoothChatService` class**

```
/**
 * This class does all the work for setting up and managing Bluetooth
 * connections with other devices. It has a thread that listens for
 * incoming connections, a thread for connecting with a device, and a
 * thread for performing data transmissions when connected.
 */
public class BluetoothChatService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
    private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

    // Unique UUID for this application

    public static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("51eb1e18-700c-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3");

    public static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("51eb1e18-700c-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3");

    //public boolean btAutoConnect = false;

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * @param context  The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state. */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
            mSecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
     * @param secure Socket Security type - Secure (true) , Insecure (false)
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
            device, final String socketType) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");

        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Listening for device ...");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothChatService.this.start();
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection Fail");
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothChatService.this.start();
        //btAutoConnect = true;
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private String mSocketType;

        public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                    "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                            case STATE_LISTEN:
                            case STATE_CONNECTING:
                                // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                                connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                        mSocketType);
                                break;
                            case STATE_NONE:
                            case STATE_CONNECTED:
                                // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private String mSocketType;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
            setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                            " socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep having connection fail on my logcat as such

```
09-01 16:11:32.085 3255-3255/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-01 16:11:32.225 3255-3255/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothChatService: connect to: C4:43:8F:98:9A:9A
09-01 16:11:32.225 3255-3255/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothChatService: setState() 1 -> 2
09-01 16:11:32.225 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout I/BluetoothChatService: BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:Insecure

                                                                                           [ 09-01 16:11:32.225  4143: 4210 E/         ]
                                                                                           ### ASSERT : external/bluetooth/bluedroid/main/../btif/src/btif_dm.c line 2025 unhandled search services event (6) ###
09-01 16:11:32.235 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
09-01 16:11:32.235 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
09-01 16:11:32.235 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothSocket: connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[54]}
09-01 16:11:34.315 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothSocket: close() in, this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@1dbcf50f, channel: -1, state: INIT
09-01 16:11:34.315 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@1dbcf50f, channel: -1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@14b9199c, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@23459fa5mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@19e76f7a impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@3dddd32b fd:FileDescriptor[54]
09-01 16:11:34.315 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothSocket: Closing mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@19e76f7a impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@3dddd32b fd:FileDescriptor[54]
09-01 16:11:34.315 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothChatService: start
09-01 16:11:34.315 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothSocket: close() in, this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@1dbcf50f, channel: -1, state: CLOSED
09-01 16:11:34.315 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout D/BluetoothChatService: setState() 2 -> 1
09-01 16:11:34.325 3255-15464/com.example.matamatamata.mdpbtlayout E/BluetoothChatService: Connection Fail
```

The error message :"connect read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my UUID to `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` and that worked for some reason. I am not exactly sure why, maybe someone who like to comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code started working by changing the UUID is that the UUID you have changed later is the UUID for **serialport**.

Whenever, a rfcomm server is created either you assign it your own UUID or it uses the **default UUID (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB)** of serialport. Now when you use your own UUID, the client application which connects to the server should also use the same UUID as the server then only connection will establish.

In your case, the client application you are using must be trying to connect to default UUID of serial port due to which when you have changed the UUID, your code started working.

[Service Discovery UUIDs](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery)